# Camera2 CameraList with External Camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm trying to get the external camera via usb, using Camera2 API. So I wanted to list all cameras of the device, and I was expecting to see the external camera id, with this code:

```
public void testCameraIdList() {

    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);

    String exCamId, backCamId , frontCamId;
    try {
        if(cameraManager != null) {
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);

                //LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL will return Value: 2
                if (facing != null && facing.equals(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL)) {
                    exCamId = cameraId;

                    Log.d(TAG, "exCamId::" + exCamId);
                }
                if (facing != null && facing.equals(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK)) {
                    backCamId = cameraId;

                    Log.d(TAG, "exCamId::" + backCamId);
                }

                if (facing != null && facing.equals(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)) {
                    frontCamId = cameraId;

                    Log.d(TAG, "exCamId::" + frontCamId);
                }
            }

        }


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exCamId is always null since it's not reachable.
From the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL), I guess the Camera2 supports external cameras. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Check if the camera supports drivers as mentioned here: https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras

Comment: The camera supports drivers, I can open it already from an application from  PlayStore. I'm using samsung s10 plus.

Comment: Could you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but hopefully this answer is useful for someone wondering about the same.

The default implementation of the camera provider HAL will explicitly not list external cameras in the `getCameraIdList()` function. It expects you to listen for available cameras via `CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback`. [The source code.](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r30:hardware/interfaces/camera/provider/2.4/default/LegacyCameraProviderImpl_2_4.cpp;l=472)

Comment: Pleas do not use a link, but the post the relevant code here.

Comment: The source is copyright The Android Source Code Project under the Apache License. It's probably OK to post it, I don't know. Since I'm not sure I'll leave the link for now.

Comment: While the linked android source is relevant, it would be much more helpful to see an example of how to use the interface correctly, since that's what the question is asking.